# React Semantic UI hide popup while click on another popup

Tags: javascript, reactjs, semantic-ui-react

I am using react semantic ui in my application. I am using semantic Popup to show tooltip. 
Problem facing:- When I click on popup button previous open Popup are not closing automatically.

```
const PopupExample = () => (
  <div>
    <Popup
      trigger={<Button icon>Click me</Button>}
      content='Content 1'
      on='click'
    />
    <Popup
      trigger={<Button icon>click me1</Button>}
      content='Content 2'
      on='click'
    />
  </div>
)

export default PopupExample
```

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is a unsolved so far in semantic-ui-react as you can see here: https://github.com/Semantic-Org/Semantic-UI-React/issues/3006

You can maybe use hover instead of click and add hoverable prop.

Comment: See my answer how to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

This is how we can achieve this:-

```
class PopUpContainer extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      popupStatus: {
        popup1: false,
        popup2: false
      }
    };
  }

  handleOpen = (keyValue) => {
    let status = {
      popup1: false,
      popup2: false
    }
    status[keyValue] = true;
    this.setState({ popupStatus: status });
  }

  handleClose = () => {
    let status = {
      popup1: false,
      popup2: false
    }
    this.setState({ popupStatus: status });
  }

  render() {

    return (
      <div className = "button-container" >
          <Popup
          trigger={<button>Click me1</button>}
          content={data.message}
          position='bottom left'
          on='click'
          open={isOpen}
          onOpen={() => handleOpen("popup1")}
          onClose={handleClose}/>

          <Popup
          trigger={<button>Click me2</button>}
          content={data.message}
          position='bottom left'
          on='click'
          open={isOpen}
          onOpen={() => handleOpen("popup2")}
          onClose={handleClose}/>
      </div>
      );
    }
  };
```